# R formula for average partial effect of linear regression with interaction terms

Tags: r

What is the most efficient way to obtain the average partial effect for a variable in a multiple linear regression model that has interaction terms?

I can do this by manually finding the mean of each interaction variable and subtracting that value in a new regression, but there must be a better way.

This is the model.

```
install.packages('wooldridge')
data(catholic,package='wooldridge')
model<-lm(math12~cathhs+cathhs*lfaminc+cathhs*motheduc+cathhs*fatheduc,data=data)
```

Is there a way to get the average partial effect for the variable "cathhs" without manually subtracting the mean from each interaction term in a new regression model?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.) This package allows you to compute many different quantities of interest, including what the documentation calls “Average Marginal Effects” (or average slopes), which sounds like what you may be looking for (the terminology in this area is super inconsistent):

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(wooldridge)
data(catholic, package='wooldridge')
model<-lm(math12~cathhs+cathhs*lfaminc+cathhs*motheduc+cathhs*fatheduc,data=catholic)

mfx <- marginaleffects(model)
summary(mfx)

          Term Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)  2.5 % 97.5 %
    1   cathhs 1.7850    0.46538   3.836 0.00012524 0.8729 2.6972
    2  lfaminc 1.8461    0.14268  12.939 < 2.22e-16 1.5665 2.1257
    3 motheduc 0.7125    0.06216  11.463 < 2.22e-16 0.5906 0.8343
    4 fatheduc 0.8928    0.05618  15.891 < 2.22e-16 0.7827 1.0029

    Model type:  lm 
    Prediction type:  response
```